# I have a server that I can ssh into using the public address but I can not access the apache2 web server that it is hosting

Tags: ubuntu, networking, webserver

I have a personal computer with Ubuntu 18.04 running an apache2 web server and OpenSSH. I have port 80 and port 22 forwarded and I have not changed the default port for apache2. I am able to access my computer via SSH from outside my home network but I cannot access my apache2 web server.

I have the output of `sudo netstat -taupen | grep LISTEN` here

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:45119         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      999        31971      1662/Plex Plug-in [ 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      123        25554      1191/mysqld         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:37585         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      999        31807      1528/Plex Plug-in [ 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:32401         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      999        29966      1302/Plex Media Ser 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      101        18268      870/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          27322      1070/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          25700      933/cupsd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:32600         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      999        29035      1629/Plex Tuner Ser 
tcp6       0      0 :::32400                :::*                    LISTEN      999        29964      1302/Plex Media Ser 
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          26336      1114/apache2        
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      0          27324      1070/sshd           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          25699      933/cupsd
```

If there is any more information I should look for, I will add that. If someone could help diagnose the problem that would be great because I cannot figure out what to look for.

Comment: Welcome! Can you see the port 80 is open from outside?

Comment: @guillermochamorro How can I check that?

Comment: Google "port open" you will have several pages that provide the service.

Comment: What does that picture show?

Comment: @guillermochamorro It says port 80 is not able to be seen, but 22 is and they are both configured the same way on my router

Comment: @roaima It is a picture of the output of me running `netstat` on my ubuntu server

Comment: So what does it show? Please paste the text. Not a picture

Comment: Your `netstat` output indicates that there's something listening only on an IPv6 address, not an IPv4 address.  Are you accessing the box remotely using IPv4?

Comment: @AndyDalton I believe so, I am just trying to access it using a phone browser

Comment: Then you might want to see why Apache is listening only for IPv6 connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research I found out that some internet service providers block certain ports (port 80, 25, and 110) by default, so that even if you forward a port through your router, the ISP might still block it. I had to call my ISP and ask them to unblock it and this resolved the issue.